# How can I know if my Swift QR Code being scanned

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

In my Project,I am building a QR Code Generator with Core Image Filters.
How can I know if other people had scan my QR code?

In other words, If I Generate a QR Code and after you read my Code. Can I show a message in my phone to told me that my Code has been used?

Comment: No.  A QR code is just a way to encode data.  Scanning it doesn't take an action inherently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QR code can't preform an action it can only display data stored in it.  I you you intend to have a QR read in your app then with in your app you could program a function to handle an event of some kind that would trigger on reading the QR code.

If you are just creating the QR code and disributing the QR code and you have pointing to a web link. Then you could create some trigger on your website that would send you a message if someone followed the link. And the key word is that the user has to FOLLOW the link provided.